# Multi-boot Windows, Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Arch in a UEFI system with one disk

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub, uefi, dualboot

### Goals:

- Multiboot, where I can select Windows, Ubuntu, Kubuntu, or Arch in the Grub menu.
- I guess only one of the Linux dists (Ubuntu?) should be in charge of the Grub EFI binary.
- But the different kernels and initrds must be updated for all the Linux dists. In other words, it should work as well as dual booting between Windows and Ubuntu.
- Preferably keep my partitioning scheme with an `EFI System Partition` and separate `/boot` and `/` partitions (as I encrypt `/`) for each dist. But if that is not possible, recommended, or convenient, re-partitioning can be done.

### What I did that did not work:

1. I installed Windows 11 (in UEFI mode),
2. Then I installed Ubuntu. At this p, point I could select Windows or Ubuntu from the Grub menu.
3. Then I installed Kubuntu. After this , step, I can choose Windows or Kubuntu (but the menu entry name is actually *still* Ubuntu).

*(I did not start the Arch step, as I already have a problem.)*

### Details

Partitions as seen from Kubuntu: (`/dev/nvme0n1` is my only disk)

```
# lsblk /dev/nvme0n1 #
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1          259:0    0  1,8T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1      259:1    0  261M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2      259:2    0   16M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p3      259:3    0  600G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p4      259:4    0  512M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p5      259:5    0  293G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p6      259:6    0  512G  0 part  
│ └─shared_linux 253:1    0  512G  0 crypt /shared_linux
├─nvme0n1p7      259:7    0    1G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p8      259:8    0  100G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p9      259:9    0    1G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p10     259:10   0  100G  0 part  
  └─kubuntu      253:0    0  100G  0 crypt /
```

Partition explanations: (with boot process-related ones emphasized)

- **`nvme0n1p1` is the EFI System Partition (ESP).**
- `nvme0n1p2`, `nvme0n1p3` and `nvme0n1p4` are Windows related.
- `nvme0n1p5` is a Veracrypt volume I'll share with all oses.
- `nvme0n1p6` is a LUKS dm-crypt (with ext4) volume I'll share between all oses.
- **`nvme0n1p7` is /boot (ext4) for Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.**
- `nvme0n1p8` is / for Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 in a LUKS dm-crypt (with ext4).
- **`nvme0n1p9` is /boot (ext4) for Kubuntu Desktop 22.04.**
- `nvme0n1p10` is / for Kubuntu Desktop 22.04 in a LUKS dm-crypt (with ext4).

For Arch, I plan to create a `/boot` partition and a `/` partition using the same pattern as Ubuntu and Kubuntu.

Comment: I have Secure Boot disabled, Windows 11 still seems to work fine. The answer can assume Secure Boot stays disabled.

Comment: There is no reason for Secure Boot to be disabled unless the environment falls into the extremely limited use case for disabling Secure Boot. Secure boot prevents malware from being injected into the bootloaders of OSes - why is it disabled? General FYI since you're multi-booting with Windows: Windows doesn't recognize GRUB, so never use `BootRec` within WinPE/WinRE - it will overwrite GRUB _(there's a specific Linux program that replicates `BootRec`'s functionality without overwriting GRUB)_

Comment: @JW0914 It was sort of out of habit, since earlier days. But I could turn it on since Ubuntu and Kubuntu works with Secure Boot (will be harder with the Arch dist though). But my current problem is actually that I don't see all Linuxes in Grub, Windows is shown and works fine.